Baumann's Cosmology: if adiabatic perturbations are generated by shifting conformal time, can't they just be gauged away?
In Baumann's Cosmology, he discusses a few aspects of adiabatic perturbations on Sec. 6.2.2. He states (p. 229)

Adiabatic perturbations can be created by starting with a homogeneous universe and performing a common, local shift in time of all background quantities, $\eta \to \eta + \pi(\eta,\mathbf{x})$.

Emphasis is his. $\eta$ denotes conformal time, $\mathbf{x}$ denotes the spatial coordinates. He then goes on to discuss some properties of the adiabatic perturbations using this construction. In particular, he argues that for two different matter components $a$ and $b$ with equations of state $w_a$ and $w_b$ their density contrasts satisfy
$$\frac{\delta_a}{1 + w_a} = \frac{\delta_b}{1 + w_b}. \tag{6.140}$$
While I follow his algebra, some conceptual aspects of this discussion are puzzling me.

Perturbations generated by $\eta \to \eta + \pi(\eta,\mathbf{x})$ are just gauge transformations, and in this sense they are not physical. So why are they relevant in this discussion? Baumann does mention something about quantum fluctuations during inflation producing perturbations like these ones, but at this level of discussion it seems to be a different choice of coordinates would preserve homogeneity.
Even if these transformations are physical, it is ensured that all adiabatic perturbations are of this type? In other words, does his derivation of Eq. (6.140) apply for any adiabatic perturbation, or only for these "gauge-induced" adiabatic perturbations?

It seems to me the issue may be related to previous choices of gauge-fixing that I couldn't keep track of. Yet, a gauge transformation of the type he described does seem to violate gauge-fixing conditions in general.

In this context, $\eta \to \eta + \pi(\eta,\mathbf{x})$ shouldn't be viewed as a gauge transformation. If you were to make that transformation in an unperturbed FLRW spacetime, you would end up with the desired density variations across each of your spatial slices, but you would be working in some weird arbitrary gauge that does not have any convenient properties -- and your spacetime would still be unperturbed FLRW.
Rather, the idea is that given some other gauge specification, adiabatic perturbations correspond to changing the density of each species in accordance with
$\rho(\eta,\boldsymbol{x}) \to \rho(\eta + \pi(\eta,\boldsymbol{x}),\boldsymbol{x})$. I think Baumann favors Newtonian gauge, but this works in principle for any gauge conditions, just with different $\pi(\eta,\boldsymbol{x})$.
All adiabatic perturbations are of this form. If a perturbation deviates from this, then it would be represented as the sum of an adiabatic perturbation and an isocurvature perturbation.

So the idea is that the unperturbed and perturbed spacetimes are related by $\eta \to \eta + \pi(\eta,\mathbf{x})$, but both of them satisfy the same gauge conditions? For instance, both of them are in Newtonian gauge?

@NíckolasAlves Well, there are other differences between the spacetimes (such as velocities and spatial curvature), and although these are determined by the density perturbations, they won't follow the same $\eta \to \eta + \pi(\eta,\mathbf{x})$ map. For example, underdense regions have future-like (low) density and past-like (high) expansion rate. I think it's more precise to say that the two spacetimes are related by $\rho(\eta,\boldsymbol{x}) \to \rho(\eta + \pi(\eta,\boldsymbol{x}),\boldsymbol{x})$ in Newtonian gauge (or whatever gauge).
